# Java and SwingSet

Tags: java

I have seen some libraries call swingset. But I am new to java and don't have any Idea what is it. Can anyone tell me what is it. I have heard about swing but no swingset

Thank you

Comment: Why don't you google for "Java swingset Stackoverflow is not a search engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just som libraries to improve Swing. I has a Grid u can connect to a ResultSet